# ACCELEO: creating file in path depending on the model structure

Tags: eclipse, acceleo, mda, emf

In an Acceleo Model to Text transformation I would like to create a file for a UML class coherent with the packages of containing the class (the class namespace in the UML model).
The problem I am facing is that I have to do that in line as the [file] command requires it so I am trying something like this

```
[file ((c.allOwningPackages().name.->sep('/')).concat(c.name.concat('.hpp')),false,'UTF-8')]
```

but I am getting this error on the concat:

```
 Cannot find operation (concat(String)) for the type (OclAny)
```

What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not mandatory to do it on the same line as the file block. The two usual ways to accomplish what you are trying to do are to

- nest the file block into a let block or
- extract the logic into another template or query.

For your example, b) would give something of the sort :

```
[template public myMainTemplate(c : uml::Class)]
    [file (getpackage(c), false, 'UTF-8')]
        ...
    [/file]
[/template]

[template private getPackage(c : uml::Class) post(trim())]
    [c.ancestors()->reverse()->sep('/')->including(c.name.concat('.hpp'))/]
[/template]
```

Note the use of "*->including*" instead of "*.concat*" for collections which is the reason why you had your error message. Of course, this was only to have all inside one single expression. It might be more readable as :

```
[template private getPackage(c : uml::Class) post(trim())]
    [c.ancestors()->reverse()->sep('/')/]/[c.name/].hpp
[/template]
```

Comment: Thank you. However the c.ancestors()->reverse() operation does not provide a meaningful result to me. I have used c.allOwningPackages().name->sep('/') and it works as you suggested. The key was putting anything I needed in a different template, I don't know why I thought it was not possible to invoke template in the file block :) again thanks